# Is there a tool or method to associate code with test cases?

Tags: selenium, integration-testing

Our website is based on java .  we use  selenium+python to test.

As stated in the title, currently encountered such a situation, the use of UI automated testing regression, took a long time, can not receive feedback in time. Is there a tool or method that can be associated with the test case. After the code is submitted, automatically identify what changes have been made, and then perform the corresponding automated test, so that the test is more targeted at present automatically ...

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting your question. It looks like your problem is in your test framework/test case design (since you mentioned it took a long time to finish the regression test). I don't think the tool to associate automated test with test case will solve your problem

Comment: for example，If  there is a  function named  Login，developer  produce   java code ,The tester produces the corresponding test case .    
when  developer  modify  the  Login  code and  commit ,I  wish  there  is a tool  that can  analysis  the code  has  been changed ,then automated test will  run the  corresponding test case.   

Therefore, it will greatly reduce the time consumption.   that  is  what  i think  about，

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if with python is possible but for java or php you can add a group tag to the tests. In this way you can run only the grop-tests that you think are necessary. This doesn´t associate tests with code but in any case you can run a subset of the tests and should take less time. Of course you have to know which group(s) to run.

Comment: Is that "TestSuite" ?  thank  you ，but  this  is  not  the answer that  i want